# Evidences for Messiah to redeem people

Tags: tanach, talmud-gemara, messiah

I read that the awaited Messiah  will cause to re-establish the Kingdom of God and redeem the Israelites so what are the evidences in Tanach and Talmud to support this claim ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one [website's](http://www.jewfaq.org/mashiach.htm) summary with textual sources (tanach, not talmud)

"The mashiach will bring about the political and spiritual redemption of the Jewish people by bringing us back to Israel and restoring Jerusalem (Isaiah 11:11-12; Jeremiah 23:8; 30:3; Hosea 3:4-5). He will establish a government in Israel that will be the center of all world government, both for Jews and gentiles (Isaiah 2:2-4; 11:10; 42:1). He will rebuild the Temple and re-establish its worship (Jeremiah 33:18). He will restore the religious court system of Israel and establish Jewish law as the law of the land (Jeremiah 33:15). "

Comment: also isaiah 10 "They shall not hurt nor destroy all my holy mountain; for the earth shall be filled with the knowledge of G-d, as the waters cover the sea" which implies re-establishing the Kingdom of God

Comment: could you also quote the verses in english

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around - if someone does these things, then he is Messiah. [רמב"ם שופטים > מלכים 8 & 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm)

Comment: could you please give English evidences

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question.

Comment: [Here it's called halacha 4 (2nd paragraph)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Chapter-11.htm)

Comment: @SethJ, it shows the question is wrong.

Comment: Leave a comment.