# XX century Aliyah, State of Israel, and righteousness of the Jews

Tags: history, state-of-israel, aliya-laaretz

(please excuse if the title does not capture the question. Feel free to edit)

On the one hand, during the first half of the XX century, a significant number of Jews returned to the land of Israel (something it seems to be called [Aliyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliyah)). Then, immediately after the WWII, the State of Israel is created.

On the other hand, it is a constant theme throughout the Tanach that the Jews prosper in the land of Israel when they adore G-d and remain loyal to the covenant/law, and are dispersed from the land when they adore other gods and do not remain loyal to the covenant/law.

Given the latter, can the former be understood in terms of some significant "repentance" and turn to righteousness by the Jews in terms of loyalty to G-d and his covenant/law?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal_teshuva_movement

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27070/3

Comment: @WAF Thanks. That does not address this issue, I think.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Interesting, but that is a post State of Israel movement. I am more interested with G-d acting in favour of the Jews leading to aliyah and the creation of the State of Israel, perhaps in response to some positive change in behaviour toward G-d.

Comment: VTC as Primarily Opinion Based. This seeks pure speculation.

Comment: @DoubleAA re your comment: I read this as asking whether any Judaism-based sources address this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Precisely. I want a theory or an author (rabbi?), or a well-argued text-based answer suggesting this is (not) the case. I'm not interested in opinions.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi David Forhman argues that this is exactly the case in a [video dvar torah](https://www.alephbeta.org/playlist/parshat-vzot-habracha)  on Parashah Haazinu as part of his Aleph Beta video series. His argument is that the process for teshuva on a national scale is outlined in Parashah HaTeshuva and the Shirat Haazinu- after sinning by worshipping other gods, etc., Am Yisrael must take steps to return to  G-d and He will help with the rest of  the process, and that by settling the Land, they were doing just that. Then most relevant part of the video is the last 3 minutes or so.  The site has a paywall but you should be able to watch a single video for free.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind adding a brief summary of the argument? Link-only answers, as far as I know, are not ideal in SE (not the least because the link could expire).