# Does the Tokhacha (Leviticus 26:14-41; Deuteronomy 28:15-68) apply to the Holocaust?

Tags: rebuke-tochacha, holocaust-shoah, ki-tavo, daniel-book-of, bechukosai

Does the curse of the Law ([Leviticus 26:14-41](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.14-41?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and [Deuteronomy 28:15-68](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.15-68?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) apply in some way to the Shoah/Holocaust?  Likewise, the prayer of Daniel in Daniel 9:4-19, in which he does not blame the Babylonians but the faithlessness of the Jewish people for the Babylonian Captivity?:

> I prayed to the Lord my God and confessed:
>
> Lord, the great and awesome God, who keeps his covenant of love with those who love him and keep his commandments, 5 we have sinned and done wrong. We have been wicked and have rebelled; we have turned away from your commands and laws. 6 We have not listened to your servants the prophets, who spoke in your name to our kings, our princes and our ancestors, and to all the people of the land.
>
> 7 “Lord, you are righteous, but this day we are covered with shame—the people of Judah and the inhabitants of Jerusalem and all Israel, both near and far, in all the countries where you have scattered us because of our unfaithfulness to you. 8 We and our kings, our princes and our ancestors are covered with shame, Lord, because we have sinned against you. 9 The Lord our God is merciful and forgiving, even though we have rebelled against him; 10 we have not obeyed the Lord our God or kept the laws he gave us through his servants the prophets. 11 All Israel has transgressed your law and turned away, refusing to obey you.
>
> “Therefore the curses and sworn judgments written in the Law of Moses, the servant of God, have been poured out on us, because we have sinned against you. 12 You have fulfilled the words spoken against us and against our rulers by bringing on us great disaster. Under the whole heaven nothing has ever been done like what has been done to Jerusalem. 13 Just as it is written in the Law of Moses, all this disaster has come on us, yet we have not sought the favor of the Lord our God by turning from our sins and giving attention to your truth. 14 The Lord did not hesitate to bring the disaster on us, for the Lord our God is righteous in everything he does; yet we have not obeyed him.
>
> 15 “Now, Lord our God, who brought your people out of Egypt with a mighty hand and who made for yourself a name that endures to this day, we have sinned, we have done wrong. 16 Lord, in keeping with all your righteous acts, turn away your anger and your wrath from Jerusalem, your city, your holy hill. Our sins and the iniquities of our ancestors have made Jerusalem and your people an object of scorn to all those around us.
>
> 17 “Now, our God, hear the prayers and petitions of your servant. For your sake, Lord, look with favor on your desolate sanctuary. 18 Give ear, our God, and hear; open your eyes and see the desolation of the city that bears your Name. We do not make requests of you because we are righteous, but because of your great mercy. 19 Lord, listen! Lord, forgive! Lord, hear and act! For your sake, my God, do not delay, because your city and your people bear your Name.”

Comment: relevant http://rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation-5768-ki-tavo-the-blessing-and-the-curse/

Comment: Highly related, in as much as one could even attempt to answer this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96500/xx-century-aliyah-state-of-israel-and-righteousness-of-the-jews/96509?r=SearchResults#96509

Comment: Does the Book of Job apply to the Holocaust ?

Comment: @Lucian You make a good point. Rabbi Sacks mentions that in his article.

Comment: @Lucian 'The poets of catastrophe during the Crusades compared their sufferings to the binding of Isaac, the tragedy of Job, and the suffering servant of Isaiah – all the cases in the Bible where suffering is not related to sin.'